# adView.loadAd() is crashing my entire program

Tags: android, admob, ads

Im trying to integrate admob ads into my app and I've been trying to follow the tutorials on Google's APIs and their code is causing my entire app to crash.

I want to think it's because I'm testing on my phone and I havent included `adRequest.addTestDevice("TEST_DEVICE_ID");` because to obtain your device id you first need to request an ad, and I am failing exactly where I am requesting an ad.

This is what I have in my main.java taken line for line from androids api tutorials. Log cat says it's crashing at `adView.loadAd(adRequest);`

```
 // Look up the AdView as a resource and load a request.
    AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Here's the XML

```
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="adUnitId"
        />
```

and finally here is what log cat has to say: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRNnA.jpg

referenced api: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals#play

Do you think it's crashing because I don't have my test device ID included? Or is there something else happening?

Comment: What is the 75th line of tha MainActivity?

Comment: You have a NullPointerException at line 75 in MainActivity.java, what do you have at that line?

Comment: It's stated above but it's 'adView.loadAd(adRequest);'

Comment: Either adView or adRequest are null... maybe verify that with a conditon...

Comment: yes that's what log cat says.....
Why is it null......
Is it because I dont have my test id?

Comment: Have you set (setContentView()) the proper XML layout that has the com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView in it?

Comment: No. The layout manager displays the ad perfectly on the screen. Also the apis dont talk about setting content view onto the ad.

Comment: It's just testing it that crashes. If I put a try catch block around line 75 it runs. It's loading the ad where it crashes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it crashing on adView.loadAd with a NullPointerException then you have no View called R.id.adView in that Activity's layout.

Look at your Activity's onCreate and what layout you have specified in setContentView. and make sure that you aren't also using something like libGDX AndroidApplication which sets it own ContentView.

Finally do a clean build.

Answer (score 1):

If you are putting the code in `MainActivity.java` and you have multiple layouts associated ie:

`activity_main.xml`
`sw600dp\activity_main.xml`
`sw720dp\activity_main.xml`

then you need to put the `com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView` xml code in each layout regardless of what device you are testing for.

That was my problem. Hope this helps others.
Also be sure the set your dependencies and change your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. When I was debugging I saw an error about the google play services version number being incorrect, and it showed the real value. I added this value to the strings.xml file:

```
<integer name="google_play_services_version">7095000</integer>
```

Once it was in, everything ran fine.